# db2 select distinct rows, but select all columns

Tags: sql, db2

Experts, I have a single table with multiple columns. col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6

I need to `select distinct (col4)`,  but I need all other columns also on my output.

If I run, this ( `select distinct(col4 ) from table1` ), then I get only col4 on my output.

May I know, how to do it on db2?.

Thank you

Comment: Assuming the following table: `create table T(c4 int,c5 int); insert into T(c4,c5) values (1,2), (1,3)`. What would the output from your query be?

Comment: I think you have to revise your question. Since every distinct value on col4 column may have different values on other columns, which value do you expect to be shown for a distinct value? ex. If you have two columns and 4 records like this: 1-A, 1-B, 2-C, 3-D and you want to show distinct values for first column, you will get only 1 and 2, but which value do you want to see next by this column? Because for the value 1, there are A or B, and for the value 2 there are C and D.

Answer (score 2):

You simply do this...

```
Select * From Table1 Where col4 In (Select Distinct(col4) From Table1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you will be able to do this.

You might try to run group by on this column. You will be able to run some aggregate functions on other columns.

```
select count(col1), col4 from table1 group by (col4);
```

Answer (score 0):

none of the answers worked for me so here is one that i got working. use group by on col4 while taking max values of other columns

```
select max(col1) as col1,max(col2) as col2,max(col3) as col3
  , col4
  from 
    table1
  group by col4
```

Comment: Um, are you sure that's what you want?  The values of the non-`col4` columns are likely from different rows.  Normally people in this situation want some form of [tag:greatest-n-per-group] result.

Answer (score -2):

At least in DB2, you can execute

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT *
FROM
<YOUR TABLE>
```

Which will give you every distinct combination of your (in this case) 6 columns.

Otherwise, you'll have to specify what columns you want to include.  If you do that, you can either use `select distinct` or `group by`.